# How to merge two UL with JQuery so that the values alternate?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-lists

I'm trying to merge two UL with JQuery so that the values alternate.
How can I merge the following :

```
  <ul id="1">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
  </ul>

  <ul id="2">
    <li>a</li>
    <li>b</li>
    <li>c</li>
  </ul>
```

To something like this :

```
  <ul id="1">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>a</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>b</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>c</li>
  </ul>
```

With JQuery ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var i=1;
$("#1 li").each(function(){
$(this).after($("#2 li:nth-child("+i+")").clone());
i++;
});

$("#2").remove();
```